# How to make "Tag" pages SEO'd in Magento?

Tags: php, content-management-system, url-rewriting, magento, e-commerce

In magento, I have SEO url rewriting enabled, and it is working fine - apart from:

- tags (showing as site/tag/product/list/tagId/1/)
- reviews (showing as, for example site/review/product/list/id/1/)
- RSS feeds (showing as site/rss/catalog/category/cid/3/sid/1/)

How come this is not SEO’d? and what will be the solution for this issue. I am more concern about my tags.
Please help

Thanks

Comment: the tag URL should be "mysite.com/tag/tag-name" not "mysite.com/tag/product/list/tagId/1/"

Comment: tag-id/1 doesn't make it not SEO'd in my opinion

Comment: It makes it as let say I have a tag "fitness-products" & the tag id is 28 then currently its making url like "mysite.com/tag/product/list/tagId/28/" and I want it to be SEO'd as"mysite.com/tag/fitness-products/"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out http://www.magentocommerce.com/extension/2282/search-engine-friendly-product-tag-urls

Comment: That's a very good news fo rme, let me try this out will let you know if it will work. +1 for you :D

Answer (score -1):

As far as I can tell, tag, reviews and RSS can't be SEO.

Only CMS, catalog are SEo'd
But for each one you can change that in the configuration (url identifier)

You should open a feature request or code your own class to do it.

I don't know the core code of Magento (just enough to build small thing with it) so maybe I'm wrong.